# How to change Asp.net Theme via Web.Config on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, build-process, publishing

**Summary**

I have a web-application with more than 5 themes. Each themes covers a completely different style for different customers. whenever we publish a new version of our application we send it for all of customers.

**The problem.**

We specify theme in web.config file in `<Page>` tag. like

```
<page theme="Theme1" /> // or Theme2 for second customer.
```

with this approach we easily change the style of application from each other without writing codes which needs a new publish for each one.

With changing the `theme="Theme1"`. nothing change and we didn't write a code in application , so why changing `theme` don't change the theme and we need a new publish?

we want to change it in `web.config` or somewhere else and with changing it the theme change without needing a new publish for each one.

---

**Update :**

I Publish Once and then copy the published version for each customer (5 times) then in each `web.config` file I change the `theme="CustomerTheme"`. but only the theme which was active in publish process is usable in all of 5 versions and other 4 themes are un-usable

--

Actually the main question is that why changes in Web.Config need a different publish while it is XML and do not need a complie. I should Add this note that, App_Theme include all of 5 themes so that all of them Compiles and are ready to use

--

This is the way I publish the application

[image: Publish]

[Photo Link](http://hajloo.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/publish.png)

---

Update 2

here IFound the exact problem reported by someone else. he resolve the problem but I can't underestand how he resolved this Issue. can anybody tell me how he resolved the issue?

he used **`aspnet_compiler command`** and told that **`automatically ADDS the 'theme' on the Page directive`**

(first post is the question and the last post is the answer)

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/495850-themes-web-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have one theme for each customer and that will not change?

Still, I do not understand your publishing scenario? Why do you want to change the Theme if each customer has its own web application?

Nevertheless, how about you check the request url in the codebehind and set the Theme Name programatically?

Pseudo-code: (you need to have this piece of code executed on every request. You could write an HTTPHandler for this, or use the BeginRequest Event in the global.asax. You also need to find which property provides the necessary URL information)

```
switch(Request.URL)
{
 case "www.customer1.com":
    Theme = "Customer1";
    break;
 case "www.customer2.com":
    Theme = "Customer2":
    break;
}
```

Comment: You underestood me 100% right. I have tochange the Theme in `Web.Config` for each customer and it will happen only once in web.config, but only the theme which I Publish with it will work and I can't change the theme for each customer, then Ihave to publish whole application for each of them. And I don't want to use code if it can have any on-the-fly solution

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean by "then Ihave to publish whole application for each of them". If you make changes to your codebase, and each customer has its own web application (in terms of IIS applications) then you definetly need to publish it for all customers, to make the changes. I think you need to explain this Theme thing a bit more

Comment: I Publish Once and then copy the published version for each customer (5 times) then in each `web.config` file I change the `theme="CustomerTheme"`. but only the theme which was active in publish process is usable in all of 5 versions and other 4 themes are un-usable

Comment: I'd update the question witha photo of the way I publish the application

Comment: Why are the others unusable? Each theme you implemented should be fully changeable during runtime. The only other thing that comes into my mind, is that you using the new .net 4.0 config transforms. You can provide 5 different publishsettings, could (at least I hope so) change the theme attribute in the web.config and use WebDeploy as your PublishMethod. Using the one-click-deployment provided by WebDeploy would make a temporary build with the selected settings and publish the changes (or full update, if you desire) to the target server. WebDeploy is so fast upon deployment.

Comment: In my company, we had a project, where the deployment onto the production server took roughly about 30 minutes, because the project had so many files in it. Now it is down to 5 minutes. Other smaller projects, that took 5 minutes for deployment, now take only some seconds. So my advice: Use WebDeploy

Comment: I don't know Why the rest of themes are unusable, and that's why I asked this question. But I do't use .net 4.0 config transforms. because I'm using Asp.net 2.0 and VS 2008. Actually the main question is that why changes in Web.Config need a different publish while it is XML and do not need a complie. I should Add this note that, App_Theme include all of 5 themes so that all of them Compiles and are ready to use.

Comment: I found a solution here `http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/495850-themes-web-config` canyou please explain how he resolved this issue. I didn't work with `aspnet_compiler command`

Answer (score 2):

Did you publish the app as precompiled? If so this could be the cause.

Why not store the theme to use in a database table and access it there rather than the web.config? This should then be truly 'on the fly'.

Comment: I exactlypublish as pre-compiled, so why it's the reason ? what's the solution then ?

Comment: I'd update the question with a photo (and a link to photo) of the wayI Publish the application, take a look please

Comment: I think you can't make changes to the site on the fly without republishing when you publish as precompiled. I would store theme based info in a database somewhere as a more updatable and easier to support solution going forward

Comment: I found a solution here `http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/495850-themes-web-config` canyou please explain how he resolved this issue. I didn't work with `aspnet_compiler command`

Comment: He doesn't appear to have found a solution, just what the problem is - the compiler was adding the theme to the page directive, i suspect whether or not you use the compiler command is irrelevant, if it is precompiled it isn't updatable on the fly...

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a really old post, I don't think the accepted answer is the best one. On this link, https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/495850-themes-web-config is a correct answer, but not as clear as it should.

He mentioned that the compiler is adding the theme to every page, so then it can't be changed by web.config file on the server. But he didn't say what to do to avoid this and it is pretty simple. You just have to remove the theme='Theme1' from web.config before compiling the web site. If it is not there, then the compiler would not set the theme to every page and you can change the theme just by web.config on every server you like with the same exact code.